# Github pages not rendering CSS correctly as it is locally

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

CSS Is not rendering as expected for the ReactApp as it is locally.

On Github

[image]

On Locally

[image]

Not attaching any code, however if you need any specific file, let me know will edit question accordingly.

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: do you see that the css is loaded correctly in the GitHub context? Like in the network tab of the dev-tools?

Comment: Yeap all seems to be fine. Updated question with screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems the position: fixed was causing the issue:

Earlier:

```
.navbar-custom {
    z-index:100; 
    position: fixed;
}
```

Later:

```
.navbar-custom {
    z-index:100; 
    /* position: fixed; */
}
```

Also, please ensure to disable caching::

[image]